# How to stop visual studio reading javascript from cache when debugging

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I am building mvc 5 website using visual studio 2013 and jQuery library 2.1.3. now my issue is cash that every time I am running and refresh website after debugging via visual studio 2013, it picks previous data. In my example I am calling jQuery plugin via document.ready function but it just not reflect new changes I made in code. I have clear cache but don't know why it is happening, never had this issue that bad before.

### puglin

```
(function ($) {
 $.fn.SetContactNoLayout = function () {
   // alert("contact no");
    this.css("color", "green");
    return this;
   };
 }(jQuery));
```

### jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {

alert("yoo");

$("a").SetContactNoLayout().addClass("greenified");

});
```

### bundle.config

```
   bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/MyCustomScript").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/CustomScript/CustomScript_01.js",
                  "~/Scripts/CustomScript/SetContactNoLayout.js",
                   "~/Scripts/CustomScript/greenify.js"
            ));
```

Comment: I assume you mean cache (not money)

Comment: sorry my fault ... correct cache

Comment: Usually you don't want to bundle at all when you debugging - it's very hard to debug the JS then.